Confused about why the regex pattern does not works
I'm using npm ls -a which gives the following ouput:
└─┬ cors@2.8.5
  ├── object-assign@4.1.1
  └── vary@1.1.2

I'm trying to extract all the dependencies  and store it in a file  with the following command:
npm ls -a | grep -o "\S+@\S+" >> deps.txt" 

Which gives nothing. I'm using macOS with bash shell.
According my understanding \S catch any non space character + is used to match one or more of such occurrence then match for @ and again for one or more occurrence of non space characters.
example dependencies text from which information have to be extracted:
According to me grep -o "\S+@\S+" should have given the result i.e all the package names along with the version information but it does not.
Interestingly when i  try with using grep -o "\S*@\S*" it gives the required information. Extracted information
I want to know why the + does not works as according to me it should work as * means it would match for 0 or more occurrences  while + means it would match for one or more occurrences of non space characters (\S+) so + should be more secure

Did you try grep -Eo? Otherwise the plus won't work without being escaped https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html

I don't use Mac, but grep matches with BRE (basic regex expressions) by default. You can modify that behavior with -E (use ERE - extended regex expressions0 or -p (perl compatible regex) All provide different features. For \S (or negated whitespace) See What does the regex \S mean in JavaScript?

Neither \S nor + are valid in basic regular expressions. Have a look here. For your case, the first chapter POSIX Basic Regular Expressions  applies.

@DavidC.Rankin i did tried with -P it throwed me an error that it is not a valid argument/ flag.

@OneCricketeer Thanks the expression worked after escaping the +. I did not know that it need to be escaped.

You have to check the man page on your mac to see what your grep supports. Open a terminal and type man grep (or man 1 grep to be specific). It will list the options. You can also just type grep --help.
